# Getting ClassCastException error

Tags: spring

I have two classes ClientLogic1 and WelcomeBean1 as follows

```
   public class ClientLogic1 {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Resource res = new ClassPathResource("spconfig.xml");
       BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res); 
       Object o = factory.getBean("id1");
       WelcomeBean1 wb = (WelcomeBean1)o; 
       wb.show();

   }

   }
```

2nd class

```
  public class WelcomeBean1 {

      private Map data;  
      public void setData(Map data) {
           this.data = data;
       }

      public void show()
      {
          Set s=data.entrySet();
          Iterator it = s.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext())
          {
              Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
              System.out.println(me.getKey()+ " - "+me.getValue());
          }
       }

    }
```

I have a xml file as

```
 <beans>
  <bean id="id1" class="WelcomeBean1">
   <property name="data">
    <map>
     <entry key="k1">
       <vlaue>1323</value>
     </entry>
     <entry key="k2">
       <value>feed</value>
     </entry>
    </map>
   </property>
  </bean>
 </bean>
```

I have given the right path.It's just when i run this program i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: WelcomeBean cannot be  
   cast to mapexmpl.WelcomeBean1 at mapexmpl.ClientLogic1.main(ClientLogic1.java:15)
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong.Can someone help me plz...

Comment: is there any WelcomeBean

Comment: I think there is a build problem, clean and build your project again

Comment: @PSR-no i have checked it but i am not using WelcomeBean anywhere in the code

Comment: @user1847395 I think before you used WelComeBean.Then changed it to WelComeBean1.Please build agian with clean.

Comment: @user1847395 did you clean build again

Comment: check this filename  Resource res = new ClassPathResource("spconfig.xml");

Comment: see here http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is saying as  `WelcomeBean` cannot be ..............But your code is showing all as WelcomeBean1.

You used WelcomeBean  some where .Please check it once.

I think before you used WelComeBean.Then changed it to  WelComeBean1.Please build agian with clean.

Comment: yes i am still getting the error and i cleaned the project too..and yes i changed the name of the class from WelcomeBean to WelcomeBean1

Comment: @user1847395 then do one thing.Rename all  WelComeBean1 to a new name called Test.Now we can definitely  get where is the problem

Comment: I changed the name of the class but its still showing the old error as below

Comment: @@user1847395 so you definitely used WelcomeBean  in somewhere otherwise how the error will come.Check in your entire project

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: WelcomeBean cannot be cast to mapexmpl.Test
 at mapexmpl.ClientLogic1.main(ClientLogic1.java:15)

Comment: no i posted the entire code above...there is nowhere i mentioned WelcomeBean

Comment: are there any other configuration files exist in the same project

Comment: yes but in seperate folder under src...but all other classes have different name

Comment: in that file will you have  WelcomeBean

Comment: nope i just checked all the config files,they are all clean...just dont know why its mapping to the old file name...anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure there is no duplicate bean id in spring configuration file. for instance you might have bean **WelcomeBean** with id **id1**
2. change to full package name `<bean id="id1" class="mapexmpl.WelcomeBean1">`